# Run processbuilder and get in and output

Tags: java, jar, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I'm trying to get my program to launch Enchanter to SSH into my server, but can't seem to figure out how to get in and output to go to `stdin` and `stdout`, or anywhere for that matter.  I just get a blank output window in Netbeans.  How to I get the Jar to run, and get input/output?

```
public class openShell {

public void openShell() throws IOException {
        String line; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder ("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\lib\\enchanter-beanshell-0.6.jar", "myscript.bsh"); 
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true); 
        Process process = builder.start();  
        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream (); 
        InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream (); 
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();  
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout)); 
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));  


        while (scan.hasNext()) { 
        String input = scan.nextLine(); 
        if (input.trim().equals("exit")) { 
            // Putting 'exit' amongst the echo --EOF--s below doesn't work. 
            writer.write("exit\n"); 
        } else { 
            writer.write("((" + input + ") && echo --EOF--) || echo --EOF--\n"); 
        } 
        writer.flush(); 

        line = reader.readLine(); 
        while (line != null && ! line.trim().equals("--EOF--")) { 
            System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line); 
            line = reader.readLine(); 
        } 
        if (line == null) { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}
}


private void LaunchButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   //openShell open = new openShell();     //RUNS BUT NO IN OR OUTPUT

   //BELOW CODE IS FOR TESTING, JUST TRYING TO GET PROCESSBUILDER TO CONNECT 
   // TO MY JAR
   try {
      ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
         "Java -jar C:\\Program Files\\Java\\lib\\enchanter-beanshell-0.6.jar"); 
      builder.redirectErrorStream(true); 
      Process process = builder.start();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 6 or 7? The ProcessBuilder API is much improved in Java 7.

Comment: I'm using 7.  Edit was to add the openShell class.

Answer (score 3):

The method `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO` will redirect your command streams in your stdin, stdout and stderr. This applies to Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] args = {
  "java", 
  "-jar", 
  "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\lib\\enchanter-beanshell-0.6.jar"
};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
```

Start with breaking up the arguments as above.  Then implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 0):

The methods `Process.getInputStream` and `Process.getOutputStream` will get you streams that you can then read from and write to.