# How to run linux command using Java Swing using onClick event?

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

I want to create an application which provides GUI using a java swing but in that application i need to use terminal to execute the commands of Linux Ubuntu OS like `sudo apt-get update` and other.

Is there any method or code which executes my command in terminal but in background when I click on any button (`on-click`  event) in form which is built using java swing?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716121/how-to-run-different-commands-from-java-code?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ProcessBuilder class I used it one of my projects to execute commands in Linux(Fedora 18) to execute a particular process.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();// This will wait untill the execution complets;
```

Comment: Take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) Java Docs for more details

Comment: Also use `SwingWorker` (or equivalent) to read the IO streams without blocking the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Runtime.exec()` methods to run commands. This creates a `Process`. You can then `waitFor` for your process to finish, read it's output for command's results, etc ...
Please see javadoc of [java.lang.Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) and [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)